# SharePoint Online /Angular - Error: Uncaught Error: Zone already loaded

Tags: angular, sharepoint, zone.js

I have created project in Angular and added in SharePoint page using Content Editor.

It was worked correctly till yesterday. but it throwing below error while loading the page.

```
zone-evergreen.js:42 Uncaught Error: Zone already loaded.
    at zone-evergreen.js:42
    at Object.pDpN (zone-evergreen.js:635)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module.hN/g (polyfills.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object.1 (polyfills.js?v=1.0:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at polyfills.js?v=1.0:1

main.ts:12 TypeError: Zone.assertZonePatched is not a function
    at new NgZone (core.js:28352)
    at getNgZone (core.js:29222)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModuleFactory (core.js:29104)
    at core.js:29162
```

Kindly check below screenshot for more details,[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To resolve this kindly add below script on your "Index.html"-

**window.Zone = undefined**

Comment: I have added code as following <script type="text/javascript"> window.Zone = undefined; </script> but isn't working.

Comment: I have added in head tag and its working thank you.

Comment: thanks folks.. that worked
Just need to know that root cause why ?

Answer (score 1):

We have exactly the same issue at the moment since today with our production customers! We have added a script editor on top of the page with the same code

```
window.Zone = undefined;
```

But what is the impact on the exisiting applications?

Answer (score 1):

Same here since today. We think Microsoft pushed an update to O365 causing this issues.

Indeed window.Zone = undefined solves this issue but we don't know yet if this impacts the rest of our applications... Still to investigate.

Comment: I have added code as following <script type="text/javascript"> window.Zone = undefined; </script> but isn't working.

Comment: Try adding a script editor on top of the page with that snippet. See if it works then.

Comment: Did anybody report that issue to Microsoft yet?
This may lead to following issues when we override SharePoint's Zone with Angular's Zone (https://angular.io/guide/zone), maybe with its Partial Page Rendering etc.

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoint-online-angular-error-uncaught-error-zone-already/m-p/2184084